# Design database to store current and initial sets of data

Tags: database, database-design

I want to design a database to store insurance policy information. (No, I'm not building Healthcare.gov)

A policy is uniquely described by it's `PolicyNumber`. Some other attributes are `EffectiveDate`, `ExpirationDate`, and `Premium` (among others).

Here's the catch - things like `Premium` and `ExpirationDate` can change after the policy has been written, due to a cancellation, audit, etc.

For my purposes, I need to know what the premium and expiration date was *as it was written* and *as it is now*.  However, there are attributes like `EffectiveDate` that will remain static from the time the policy was written.  So, how do I build a normalized database to capture all of this?

Comment: You may in interested in reading about [slowly changing dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension).

Comment: The approach I generally prefer is to treat different rows as *unique instances* and to not allow modifications once created. For an example like this, a *new* policy would be created any time a change was made, such that the original was never altered (the "new policy ID" or "sequence ID" would be part of a FK).

Comment: try this http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2009/11/29/versioned-data/

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to create a normal policy table that would contain all the up-to-date information. Create another table that would contain the history data you wish to track. You may want to keep timestamp information on both but specially on the history table. You may want to build a 1-M relationship between the main table and the history table since you could have several history rows for any active row. The absence of history rows would mean that there are no changes made.

Every time a change is made, the current row in the policy table (or if you wish, the relevant columns) are copied to the history table and the history row is saved.

A problem with this design is that it may be a bit of work to figure out what changed (unless the client could pass this info) and that it would waste some space.

This design has the advantage of being simple and that it keeps all current information in 1 place. Current information is what you'd normally access in most of the system's operations (I'd guess).